# Setting values in one dataframe from the boolean values in another

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe, boolean

I have a MWE that can be reproduced with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]], columns=['A', 'B'])
b = pd.DataFrame([[True,False],[False,True]], columns=['A', 'B'])
```

Which creates the following dataframes:

```
In [8]: a
Out[8]: 
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4

In [9]: b
Out[9]: 
       A      B
0   True  False
1  False   True
```

My question is, how can I change the values for dataframe `A` based on the boolean values in dataframe `B`?

Say for example if I wanted to make `NAN` values in dataframe `A` where there's an instance of `False` in dataframe `B`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need replace `False` to `NaN`:

```
print (a[b])
     A    B
0  1.0  NaN
1  NaN  4.0
```

or:

```
print (a.where(b))
     A    B
0  1.0  NaN
1  NaN  4.0
```

and if need replace `True` to `NaN`:

```
print (a[~b])
     A    B
0  NaN  2.0
1  3.0  NaN
```

or:

```
print (a.mask(b))
     A    B
0  NaN  2.0
1  3.0  NaN
```

Also you can use [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) or [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with some scalar value:

```
print (a.where(b, 7))
   A  B
0  1  7
1  7  4

print (a.mask(b, 7))
   A  B
0  7  2
1  3  7

print (a.where(b, 'TEST'))
      A     B
0     1  TEST
1  TEST     4
```

Comment: That does seem to work, thanks. Just to expand upon my question, is it possible to make all False values in dataframe B into the string 'TEST' in dataframe A? I'm interested to see how flexible I can be with this kind of mapping.

Comment: Thanks, interesting this doesn't seem to work with multi-index dataframes.

Comment: Hmmm, `Dataframes` with `Multiindex` have same `indexes` and same `columns`?

Comment: Yes, or rather more specifically in my example, I have 2 dataframes, both have the same index (time series) and the same set of multi-level columns (7 levels). The above methods don't work with those.

Comment: Then try add `values` `print (a.mask(b.values))`

Comment: I think about it and you use [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) only instead define boolean mask use dataframe `b`. So `a[b]` works same  as `a[a < 1]`, only boolean mask is different.